# Get the data using its ID

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

HI in this code am not able to get the sort listed field for an example Please check the code below.

**In My User collection**

```
[{
       user_name : 'ssssss',
       user_email : 'xxx@gmail.com'
}]

 db.user.find({}, { $projection:  user_name:1 }).toArray()
```

**My output is like**

```
[{
       user_name : 'ssssss',
       user_email : 'xxx@gmail.com'
}]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
  [{
           user_name : 'ssssss'
  }]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this, in here as you need only user_name you can set it to 1 and also, you don't need id you can set it to 0.

```
db.users.find( {}, { user_name: 1, _id: 0 } )
```

You will be able to find more details [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-specified-fields-only).

Answer (score 1):

```
let aggrQuery = [
    { '$match': {} },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "user_name": 1,
        }
    }
]
users.aggregate(aggrQuery).exec((err, result) => {
    res.json({
        userDetails: result
    })
})
```

Comment: Hope this will help.